# Golang compile to binary from AST

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

Is it possible to compile an AST to a binary in Golang? Or does the API not expose that feature. The way libraries currently do this, such as [Gisp](http://github.com/jcla1/gisp), is to print out the AST using the go/printer package. Is there a way to skip this process and compile the AST directly to a binary?

Comment: No, there is not currently a way to do that

Comment: this would be awesome to compile directly from AST... heh

Comment: yes, or at least support generating source from AST.

Answer (score 2):

Not at the moment, no. Right now, although Go's compiler is written in Go, it's [not exposed in the standard library](https://golang.org/pkg/go/).

The Gisp method, of printing the source and using `go build`, is probably your best option.

Answer (score 2):

well, gisp is really cool but theres a trick to use the original go parser to create that ast:

you can create a local symlink to the compiler/internal/syntax folder:

```
ln -s $GOROOT/src/cmd/compile/internal/syntax
```

now your code can read a file and create an ast out of it like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/me/gocomp/syntax"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    filename := "./main.go"
    errh := syntax.ErrorHandler(
        func(err error) {
            fmt.Println(err)
        })
    ast, _ := syntax.ParseFile(
        filename,
        errh,
        nil,
        0)
    f, _ := os.Create("./main.go.ast")
    defer f.Close()
    syntax.Fdump(f, ast) //<--this prints out your AST nicely
}
```

now i have no idea how you can compile it.. but hey, at least you got your AST ;-)

Comment: I was under the impression that the AST used by the compiler was quite different from the one in `go/ast`. If so, it may not preserve comments and formatting, and any examples/blogs/SO answers dealing with `go/ast` will be of little help.